# Play 2.0 Ajax Call To Re-render Part Of A Form

Tags: jquery, playframework

I want to re-render a portion of a form with an ajax call in Play 2.0.

So, I have a form that calls a jQuery load to re-render a sub portion of that form.  The form template includes the sub template that I want to re-render.  So, I already have the proper portion of the form in its own template.  The difficulty arises because that template is included in the parent through a repeat.  And, that repeat automagically converts the backing data model into a Play Field object.  I can't seem to construct a Field on my own, but should I even be trying too?  Given the dearth of information about this, I clearly must be doing something radically wrong here ...

So, the top level form looks something like this:

```
@(dataForm: Form[dataModel])
...

<div class="container">
...
    @helper.form(action = routes.customerData.validate, args='class -> "form-horizontal") {
...
        @repeat(dataForm("metaData")) { metaData =>
...
            @metaDataDiv(metaData)

</div>
```

And, the div sub template looks something like this:

```
@(metaData: play.api.data.Field)
...

<div class="row-fluid" id='expandedView@metaData("metaId").value' style="display: none;">
...
</div>
```

And, the ajax call looks something like this:

```
$('[id="' + metaDataContainerId + '"]').load(fetchMetaDataUrl, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        showAjaxError(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Finally, the Controller function looks like this:

```
public static Result fetchMetaData(...)
{
    ...

    MetaData metaData = ...;

    play.api.data.Field field = new Field(null, ????, ...);  ????

    return ok(????.render(?????));
}
```

So, is any of this vaguely correct?  Should I just embed my sub template in a simple
form and use a JQuery selector on the resulting html? Is there some (other) way to 
re-render a portion of a form through an ajax call?

Comment: You are on the way. You just need to bind data from the xhr using a `Form` object.